# How to make icon from iconjar keep pixel perfect once dragged into Sketch?

Tags: export, sketch-app

When I dragged a pixel perfect icon (svg) from Iconjar to Sketch, the icon always off grid and exported with blurry result. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select **Sketch->Preferences...** form menu, then check **Pixel Fitting** from **General** tab as shown on screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Yes I have those options enable when drag icons but still, it's off grid :(